# Is the AI also limited by line-of-sight/fog of war, radar range or stealth?

Tags: supreme-commander

Is the enemy AI in Skirmish mode also limited, like human players, by what they can see or detect with the radar, or do they (like the AI in many other RTS games) see everything the other players do? I'm wondering if I can still use [stealth](http://supcom.wikia.com/wiki/Stealth_unit) to get by [detection](http://supcom.wikia.com/wiki/Intel) by the AI, and if I also need to counter their scouts or radars to prevent them from getting information about my base or unit movement.

If yes, what if 'Fog of War' is disabled? Also, will this affect their long range weapons (artillery, missile launchers, etc.)? (Will they only hit what can be seen within their line-of-sight or radar range?)

Note: I usually play against [Sorian AI](https://code.google.com/p/sorian-ai-mod/), but also sometimes puts the default AI into the mix. Info regarding either AI are welcome. Also, I am playing Supreme Commander: Forged Alliance (expansion), not the first Supreme Commander game.

**Is the AI also limited by line-of-sight/fog of war, radar range or stealth?**

Comment: From here, https://code.google.com/p/sorian-ai-mod/ `The AI will now gather and react to Intel.` This implies it is limited (in that it has to gather intel). Not posting as an answer though as I've not checked further and this obviously only applies to the Sorian AI.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett I see. I'm looking for more details as to what intel it already knows or still has to find out, and how it deals with the 'Fog of War' game option. I also would like to know of details regarding the default AI behavior.

Comment: I think it depends highly on the difficulty setting of the AI.  At least I remember in SC2, the AI on the hardest difficulty cheats like mad.

Comment: @spartacus In Supreme Commander: FA, there are separate 'cheating' versions of the AI. They are marked as 'AIx'. The only cheats I know that they do are getting extra resources and faster build time. I'm not sure if they cheat in another way (like full map visibility). I'm also not sure if the supposed to be non-cheating regular AI, 'cheats' when it comes to map visibility.

Comment: You can test this empirically using appropriate units. If your stealthed cybran aircraft are not hit by SAM sites while out of visual range of any enemy unit, the stealth is working as advertised. It they are hit by SAM missiles, the AI is cheating. UEF frigates create spoofed radar copies of themselves, so more long ranged fire should miss them compared to non radar spoofing units. Or just move a T2 Cybran radar jammer toward the AI base and see when the AI starts shooting at it. Visual range means the jamming worked, out of site kills means jamming failed.

Comment: @MarkRipley that's not whats being asked about, which is units functioning differently in Human v Human than AI v Human. The question is does the AI have more knowledge of game state than a Human

Answer (score 1):

In general both the sorian AI and vanilla AI get information they wouldn't as a human player.

both AIs are night and day, however, with how much information they have.

The vanilla AI of the game plays with full map visibility at all times.

This is flagrant when you build your first fighter and instantly all of the AI's fighters are ordered from across the map to attack it even though the AI has not yet scouted your base and at present has no way of knowing you built air units at all.

But sorian AI does have fog of war and relies on what are called "map markers" which not all maps feature to be able to orient itself and recognise points of interest. It also recognises and adapts to the terrain going as far as to evaluating line of sight because of terrain height and avoiding shooting into the ground. It's choices are dictated by many many run-throughs within a neural network to determine the most optimal choices added to a heafty amount of human guidance. Such as for build orders and general meta choices and mechanics use such as transport drops of engineers and troops.

Sorian will notify you in chat if the map you chose to play with does not have map markers and that it is therefore unable to play.

note that there is a distinction between AI and AIx for Sorian whereby AI plays with normal resources and conditions a human player would have and AIx has a multiplier to it's economy, thereby classifing it as a "cheating" AI (and a very interesting and fun challenge to beat).